# react & nodeJS - HTTP always send OPTIONS instead regular methods

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors

I tried to search about the issue a few days without understanding.

If you can explain how can I open all requests as regular and block 'OPTIONS' option it will be the best!

I'm trying to send HTTP PUT, GET, POST, DELETE methods with 'React' fetch.
with POST, sometimes the server accept the requests, sometimes the fetch fails.
with PUT / DELETE all the time the server getting OPTIONS request instead of the regular methods.
I tried to learn about cors without a lot of understanding.

there are my backend and frontend example:

backend:

```
router.put('/privacy', (req, res) => {
let user = req.body.user,
    decision = req.body.decision,
    file = req.body.filename;

FileModel.findOne({'metadata.filename': file, 'uploadedBy': user}, function(err, file){
    let errMsg = `change privacy of ${file} failed.`

    if (err) {
        res.json({
            ok: false,
            msg: errMsg
        });

    } else if (file) {
        switch (decision) {
            case 'private': {
                file.isPrivate = true;
                file.save();
                res.json({
                    ok: true
                });
                break;
            }
            case 'public': {
                file.isPrivate = false;
                file.save();
                res.json({
                    ok: true
                });
                break;
            }
            default: {
                res.json({
                    ok: false,
                    msg: 'wrong decision'
                });
            }
        }

    } else {
        res.json({
            ok: false,
            msg: errMsg
        });
    }
});
```

});

app.js (backend):

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3001' , credentials :  true}));
```

app.use('/api', api);

front-end:

```
onSaveClicked = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/manage/privacy', {
        crossDomain: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
        },
        body: {
            filename: this.state.name
        }
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => json.result)
          .then(result =>{
              this.setState({files: result});
          });
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You can't block the OPTIONS requests. If `http://localhost:3000` is a different origin, you must enable CORS for your API.

Comment: can you explain please how can i do that? note that in the end it will be the same origin (3001 its only for development..)

Comment: Are you using webpack dev server? If so you want to configure the dev server to proxy the requests so you can use same origin. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

Comment: what error are you getting on frontend? can you post some chrome network logs? any error logged on backend as well? you might want to catch error on frontend as well `.catch(console.error)` @EliranSuisse

Comment: @Theo , network or console - there is nothing appear, only the "fetch" method from the front-side return the exception. (my printing). I all the time getting OPTION method in the server side. .

Comment: POST /api/login 200 164.081 ms - 221
OPTIONS /api/login 204 0.155 ms - 0

Comment: ok that's a good sign @EliranSuisse so your API works since you get code 200. can you print the response on both server and client?

Comment: can you simplify your client code btw? i don't think the `.then` chain doesn't work like that. try this
https://gist.github.com/shierro/461b75efd3f437324c7e659fa876a07d @EliranSuisse

Comment: @Theo I took your code and paste it, and everything is the same.

Comment: there is the inputs: when server got OPTION: OPTIONS /api/login 204 2.352 ms - 0

Comment: when the server accept some post method, it printing SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)                    while the browser printing ::::localhost/:1 Failed to load http://localhost:4000/api/login: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: ok first, we need to fixt the server side error.can you also try plain `cors()`? also, can you specify express version & the middlewares that you use? maybe create a gist containing your middlewares? we need to determine w/c part of the server code the error is coming from @EliranSuisse

Comment: @Theo firstly thank you, can we continue discussing in chat or something like this? my email is elikos1@gmail.com

Comment: ok let's continue discussing it here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177876/17800

Comment: I cant chatting with you because I have under 20 rec..

Answer (score -1):

You only need to alter the cors middleware options to

```
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' , credentials :  true }))
```

Comment: I tried to do that with no success, maybe something with the request is wrong? still getting options request. ..

Comment: note that if i sending a regular post using form is working nice, only when im using the fetch option..

Comment: Then you need to handle the OPTIONS request on the backend with `app.options('*', cors( { origin: '*' , credentials :  true } ))`

Comment: still not working.. did both of them, note that : at the first time the server accept me, then if I log out and try to re signin the fetch is fail.

Comment: "" POST /api/login 200 164.081 ms - 221
OPTIONS /api/login 204 0.155 ms - 0 ""